# Android - Gradient Weirdness

Tags: android, drawable, gradient

I have a GridView of "Tiles", each of which has the following as their `android:background` property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:gradientRadius="180"
        android:startColor="#55FFFFFF"
        android:type="radial" />

</shape>
```

When the scrollable grid initially renders, a tile looks like this:

[image]

After the list is scrolled downward, even just a single pixel, ALL of the tiles then have this new, pixelated looking gradient:

[image]

The gradient is on a Relative layout, defined as such (which has inside it an ImageView for the star, a TextView, etc):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tile_image_layout_gradient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/radialbg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" />
```

The particular phone that this is breaking on is an Experia, running Android 2.3.4. The Galaxy S3 seems to render it fine, but any 4.x based x86 emulators also have the same problem with artifacting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, try setting this in your `onCreate()` method, before `setContentView()`:

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

You'd also MAYBE need to set the background programatically in this case, not through xml.

Comment: The pixel format didn't fix it, when would you suggest trying to set the BG programmatically?

Comment: Actually, that did work, when I moved from onAttach to onCreate

Answer (score 2):

Add the following override to your activity,  This ought to fix the color banding issue you are seeing by setting the window format to support more colors.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

More info : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFormat(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFormat%28int%29)

Comment: I moved it to onCreate as Mosquito suggested, and it works. Thanks a lot!